# Python 2.7.10 Runs Code Differently on 2 Different Computers

Tags: python, windows

My program runs as intended on my desktop, but not on my laptop, even though it has the same version of Python installed.

- The desktop runs Windows 7 and
- The laptop ran Windows 8.1, but I upgraded to Windows 10 to see if that solved the problem. It did not.

Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
import random

count = 0
food_list = [
    "Pizza", 
    "Italian", 
    "Hamburger", 
    "Sandwiches", 
    "Salads",
    "Chinese",
    "Seafood",
    "Mexican",
    "French",
    "Deli",
    "Indian"
]
food_choices = []

# Header and description text
print " "
print "*" * 30
print "*" * 30
print " "
print "Food Options 1000"
print " "
print "Tell the Food Options 1000 how many options you want to select from"
print "and it will provide you with that amount of appropriate food choices."
print " "
print "*" * 30
print "*" * 30
print " "
# --- End header and description text ---

print "You have a total of %d choices from which to choose." % len(food_list)
print " "

# Receive user input and assign to a variable
optNum = int(raw_input("How many options do you want to have? "))

# Show how many choices user selected
print " "
print "Your %d choices are: " % optNum
print " "

# Run while loop until user selection integer is met
# Print food choices in the amount of user chosen number
while count != optNum:
    fc = random.choice(food_list)
    if fc not in food_choices:
        food_choices.append(fc)
        count += 1

for i in food_choices:
    print i

print " "
print " "
```

My results from the desktop:

> How many options do you want to have? 8
>
> Your 8 choices are:
>
> Salads Deli Mexican Chinese Pizza Hamburger French Sandwiches

The results from the laptop:

> How many options do you want to have? 8
>
> Your 8 choices are:
>
> Salads Deli Mexican Chinese Pizza Mexican French French

UPDATE:

I moved the file to the laptop via USB stick as recommended by f.rodrigues. The file on the stick works properly and does not show repeats. There was somehow a missing line at 47 in the copy-paste code.

Thank you to all.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that you're running the exact same code on both computers?

Comment: Could you explain how the code runs differently? What is your expected result? Post the results from each platform. Are you sure you have the correct version of python on both systems? And all dependencies installed?

Comment: Yes, I cut and pasted the entire code to the file on the laptop through remote assistance while both computers had the code on the screen.

Comment: @NewPyGuy Please **edit the question** with the details, and not post them via comments.

Answer (score 1):

I find it hard to believe that you are using the SAME code.

You said that you copy-pasted it to the other machine.

If that's the case something might have gone wrong in this process, maybe your IDE is messing up the indentation. (maybe due to miss usage of tabs and spaces as indentation)

Something like this could happen:

```
while count != optNum:
    fc = random.choice(food_list)
    if fc not in food_choices:
        food_choices.append(fc)
    count += 1
```

Which is completely different than this:

```
while count != optNum:
    fc = random.choice(food_list)
    if fc not in food_choices:
        food_choices.append(fc)
        count += 1
```

A simple indentation missing can have varying results. In this case it would add less items to `food_choice`.

EDIT:

[msw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/282912/msw) states that in the OP question both lists have 8 items, only that the second has duplicates.

For this I think the discrepancy comes from this:

```
while count != optNum:
    fc = random.choice(food_list)
    food_choices.append(fc)
    count += 1
```

The line to check for uniqueness is not there.

This would get the same number of items in the list, but it might have duplicates.

This is a bit far-fetch from the copy-paste problem I started.

The only way I see could be done to be completely sure is to use the same file, not copying it. Use a usb stick, or upload/downlaod it online.

Comment: It appears that the OP's loop, while un-pythonic, is indented properly. Each of the two runs shown ask for 8 items and show 8 items.

Comment: Yeah, I don't trust what the OP writes as being valid, either, because the duplicates are not caught.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem arises because you are using a *random* number generator. The pseudo-random algorithm starts with a seed value. If you do not explicitly seed it, it will seed itself with the time of day (or some other arbitrary number). So every time you run your program, the numbers generated by `random` will be different. This allows you to set the random generator to the same starting seed, so all runs will give the same result. If you use `random.seed('myseed')` or even `random.seed(4)` at the beginning of the program, then each run will be identical.

The second problem with your code is that you are using `random.choice()` to select your choices; you will get duplicates this way, like "French French" in your example output. Better to use `random.sample(food_list, optNum)` where [sample](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample) is described as

> Return a k length list of unique elements chosen from the population sequence. Used for random sampling without replacement.
>
> Returns a new list containing elements from the population while leaving the original population unchanged. ...

Comment: I started thinking about this too, but the line `if fc not in food_choices:`  and the block bellow it would be the same as using `random.sample()`.